# Cannot configure VNC Server on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: vnc, vncserver, realvnc

I installed the VNC Connect 6.0.2 software tool on a Windows Server 2012 R2 virtual machine. The install completed without any issue and I can launch the VNC Client tool, however I cannot see the VNC Server tray icon from which I should be able to configure the server account and/or server key.

When looking at both the Task Manager and the Services, I can see the vncserver item running as expected. However, because the tray icon is not available, I don't know how to configure the server.

I am using VNC Connect 6.0.2 on two other computers, a Win 7 and a Win 10, and both display the VNC server tray icon and can be configured successfully. Is Windows Server edition different in any way or do I need to configure VNC Server differently?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running "vncserverui.exe" from the VNC install directory (or similarly named, I'm running version 5, but look for the EXE with "UI" in the name).  You may have to "Run as Administrator" depending on your UAC settings and how the service was loaded.

Comment: I did try to run all executables from the VNC Server install folder and most are returning a dialog stating "This program is not intended to be run directly". When running "vncserverui.exe" I get this message no matter if running as administrator or not.

Comment: In addition to that,  from the VNC Server install folder I can run "vncserver.exe" which launches the VNC Server in User Mode. However, to use this mode, at least a Pro account is required therefore I cannot use it this way.

Comment: Are you viewing the desktop of your machine over RDP? The UI for the service mode server (including the tray icon) doesn't get displayed in RDP sessions.

Answer (score 0):

When you install  your VNC please do the following steps (my VNC is the enterprise one):

- Log in into your web account
- Go to Deployment section
- Generate your TOKEN

During installation

- tick add the firewall role,
- remove some mirror feature if you do the installation via RDP.

You have to run the following commands using CMD as admin:

- vnclicense.exe -add yourKEY - the key is displayed in the table below,
- vncserver.exe -service -joinCloud TOKEN [-joinGroup GROUP-NAME]
  , the group name is displayed in the top right corner.

After these steps on your web account, there should be visible another computer with a padlock.
Manage its permission by pressing this button, in the pop-up window add Everyone ...... to the top window.

On the client side install VNC viewer and try to log into it using one of your server's accounts.

Check as well the firewall because on my server after installation all ports were open for VNC, leave 5900 for both UDP and TCP.

Using these steps I have already added 3 computers.